# $table.bootstrapTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to use bootstrap-table to export seleted rows from a table in CSV but i'm getting this error : **$table.bootstrapTable is not a function**

Any idea how to fix it please? Is there another way to make selected rows downloaded in CSV using javaScript or jQuery ?

I'm including these scripts for bootstrap-table:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="tableExport.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.base64.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you are not including the actual bootstrap-table JavaScript code itself (`bootstrap-table.js`).

Have a look at this [example](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/from-data.html) (source [here](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/options/from-data.html)); refer specifically to the `<script>` includes there.

If you provide a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example, I can provide more specific feedback.

Comment: @Maha Did this answer help?

Answer (score 0):

see this section at the beginning of the module:

```
try {
bootstrapVersion = parseInt($.fn.dropdown.Constructor.VERSION, 10);
```

}
catch (e) {}

parseInt can return NaN so the ideal is to do (after try):

```
if (bootstrapVersion != 3 && bootstrapVersion != 4)
bootstrapVersion = 3;
```